# Can a variable be used in Mysql query after WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

the below query works and returns results

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE District = '" . $var . "' ORDER BY Form_Date DESC";
```

where as  if I substitute the word "District" with a variable, it doesn't work

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE '" . $distvar . "' = '" . $var . "' ORDER BY Form_Date DESC";
```

what is wrong with this one and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotes surrounding the field you are testing for, or replace them with backticks to save you from the mysql parser mistaking it for a potentially reserved word:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `" . $distvar . "` = '" . $var . "' ORDER BY Form_Date DESC";
```

Comment: Alternatively, backticks `\`` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `" . $distvar . "` = '" . $var . "' ORDER BY Form_Date DESC";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " . $distvar . " = '" . $var . "' ORDER BY Form_Date DESC";
```